# The dual of the general product of normed spaces is isometrically isomorphic to the product of the duals

Tags: functional-analysis

The question is an exercise 4 in Conway's Functional Analysis of chapter 3 section 5 , followed by

Let $\left\{\mathscr{X}_i: i \in I\right\}$ be a collection of normed spaces. If $1 \leqslant p<\infty$, show that the dual space of $\oplus_p \mathscr{X}_i$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\oplus_q \mathscr{X}_i^*$, where $1 / p+1 / q=1$.

where $\|\cdot\|$ denote the norm on each $\mathscr{X}_i$. And for $1 \leqslant p<\infty$,
$$
\oplus_p \mathscr{X}_i \equiv\left\{x \in \prod_i \mathscr{X}_i:\|x\| \equiv\left[\sum_i\|x(i)\|^p\right]^{1 / p}<\infty\right\} .
$$

In my opinion, it suffices to prove for every element $f \in (\oplus_p \mathscr{X}_i)^*$, there exists $y=(y_i)\in\oplus_q \mathscr{X}_i^*$ s.t. $f$ can be uniquely represented by the form $f:\oplus_p \mathscr{X}_i\to \mathbb{F}\quad (x_i)\mapsto \sum\limits_{i\in I}y_i(x_i)$, and $\|f\|=\|y\|_q$, where  $\mathbb{F}$ is  a notation in Conway's book, denoted by $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

To prove this, on one hand, we let $y=(y_i)\in\oplus_q \mathscr{X}_i^*$, and then use Hölder's inequality
$$
|f(x)|=|\sum\limits_{i\in I}y_i(x_i)|\leqslant \sum\limits_{i\in I}\|y_i\|\|x_i\|\leqslant \|x\|_p\|y\|_q
$$
hence $\|f\|\leqslant \|y\|_q$, then $f\in (\oplus_p \mathscr{X}_i)^*$.

On the other hand, if $f\in (\oplus_p \mathscr{X}_i)^*$, let $e_i:\mathscr{X}_i\to\oplus_p \mathscr{X}_i$ be the natural embedding. Then we let $y_i=f \circ e_i$, we can easily have $y_i\in\mathscr{X}_i^*$. However, I have difficulty proving the fact $y=(y_i)\in\oplus_q \mathscr{X}_i^*$, can anyone give some hints? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Restrict a functional in the product to each fiber. That will allow you to represent a functional in the product as an element in the product of duals.

Comment: I try to let $J$ a finite subset of $I$,and $x=(x_i)$, where $x_i=\|y_i\|^{q-1}t_i$ if $i\in J$, $x_i=0$ if $ i\notin J$, and then we have $|\sum\limits_{i\in J}\|y_i\|^{q-1}y_{i}(t_i)| \leq \|f\|(\sum\limits_{i\in J}\|y_i\|^q)^{1/p}$, but I don't know how to operate next.

Comment: I think we can let $|y_i(t_i)|\to \|y_i\|$, but I don't know how to let $y_i(t_i)\to \|y_i\|$